# Verify field value is correct before updating SharePoint list

Tags: javascript, validation

https://stackoverflow.com/users/9823939/fernandog helped a great deal adding a "Please Select" to my drop down options. Now I need to add code to check if reason=="Please Select" when Save button is clicked and if TRUE - Highlight Reason Drop Down Field and alert ("Please Select Reason")  ELSE - Update()

Changing the settings on the SharePoint list did not help.

```
function Save(){
SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", 'SP.ClientContext', function()
{
try
{
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = clientContext.get_web();
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Invoice History');

        var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);  

        oListItem.set_item('InvoiceID', window.frameElement.dialogArgs.InvoiceID); 
        oListItem.set_item('Title',window.frameElement.dialogArgs.InvoiceNo); 
        oListItem.set_item('RejectionReason',$("#ddlRejection option:selected").text()); 
        oListItem.set_item('Description', $("#rejectionComment").val()); 

        oListItem.update();
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        alert(err.message);
    }
});}
function onQuerySucceeded(){
update();
}
```

I want to add verification that the user selected a reason before creating the item on the Invoice History list.

Comment: You can use `$("#ddlRejection").val()` to read the `value` of the selected option. Compare it to `""` or `"-1"` or what have you to find out whether the user has selected a valid value before running the function. I'll also point you to this: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/5734311)

Comment: Thanks Chris - didn't understand expectations before reading that...